# Can a Windows application intercept a clicked link in an email?

Tags: windows, hyperlink

I understand about Windows allowing a single "editor" for the http "file" type; I don't want to fight with the browsers over that.

Does Windows have any other mechanism for processing links?

Answer (score 0):

It is called [asynchronous pluggable protocols](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767916%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: This pertains only to IE, AFAIK. However, in Windows a [Protocol Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb266531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can be setup (e.g. "syssync://") which is then associated with the "Open verb". This is similar to how normal file-extensions are mapped via the "Open verb".

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a doomed experiment, however I will leave you with these links:

[Custom] protocols can be registered via a [Protocol Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb266531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). URIs opened with the "Open verb" will be resolved through these handlers. Similarly, files opened with the "Open verb" can be handled by [registering a Verb for the given file extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Of course the above *does not affect* the "Choose File" dialogs nor is it absolute; for instance, a browser may choose to always "Save As.." a file instead of "Open"ing it based on user preference.

Happy coding.